All web transactions are categorised as /DispatcherServlet in newrelic
In my application performance monitoring (APM) dashboard, all API transactions across my microservices are grouped under /DispatcherServlet. The microservices are built using Spring Boot version 3.1.1 and Java version 17.
Here's the setup: I have multiple microservices, most of which correctly group their requests under /DispatcherServlet, except for one. However, all microservices share the same Java agent. Each microservice operates on Spring Boot version 3.1.1 and Java version 17.
What could be causing this discrepancy, and how can I resolve it?
Upon investigation, I noticed that in the microservice where transactions are grouped correctly (e.g., Employees(GET)), the transaction trace shows:
Servlet/org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet/service
Java/{controllername}/{API Endpoint}
Database connection calls

However, in the microservices where requests are incorrectly grouped under /DispatcherServlet, the transaction trace shows:

Servlet/org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet/service
Database connection calls
(The Java/{controllername}/{API Endpoint} section is missing.)

I haven't enabled enable_auto_transaction_naming configuration, and I haven't made any code configuration changes in either of the applications.

It got resolved by upgrading newrelic agent
